# GEE: Error moving an image collection asset into a folder

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-explorer

When trying to drag and drop an `image collection` cloud asset into a folder from the Assets browser in Earth Engine Code Editor, I get the following error:

> ### Asset error
>
> Before trying to move an asset, delete its children: 'projects/ee-ekyzivat/assets/planet-test'.

Any ideas what might be causing it, or do you think it's a bug? Perhaps this operation is better suited to the python or java APIs or the `earthengine` command line interface?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to move or rename an `imageCollection` when there are images in it. What I usually end up doing is a bit of a workaround: first creating a new IC at the desired location or with the desired name, then use the command line tool to move (`mv`) or copy (`cp`) each of the images there:

```
earthengine mv users/oldFolder/oldImageCollection/imageName users/newFolder/newImageCollection/imageName
```

To get the assetIds of all images in the collection, you can use `ls`:

```
earthengine ls users/folder/nameOfImageCollection
```

If there are a lot of images in the collection, it could be useful to write a bash script to go over each of them.

Comment: This works, thanks! I agree it's a little clunky since it requires writing a shell script.